# Explain performance differences between different LINQ statements

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to wrap my head around the following problem:

I am trying to optimize this query:

```
(from ur in UserRates
 where ur.BillingProperty == null
    && ur.JobPosition == null
    && ur.ValidFrom.Date <= date
    && (ur.ValidTo ?? DateTime.MaxValue).Date >= date
 orderby ur.ValidFrom descending
 select ur).FirstOrDefault();
```

No this can take up to 10 seconds.

Now I tried playing around with LINQ method chaining and managed to get it down to a second with this statement:

```
UserRates.OrderByDescending(u => u.ValidFrom)
     .FirstOrDefault(u =>
         u.ValidFrom.Date <= date
     && (u.ValidTo ?? DateTime.MaxValue).Date >= date
     && u.BillingProperty == null
     && u.JobPosition == null);
```

Then I was wondering, why this SQL query uses around 0 seconds to execute:

```
SELECT *
FROM UserRate
Where ValidFrom <= @date
  AND (ValidTo >= @date OR ValidTo IS NULL)
  AND BillingPropertyID IS NULL
  AND JobPositionId IS NULL
  AND [UserId] = @UserId
```

The @date and @userId are being filled with the same values, as the code is using.

Then I switched around the LINQ call

```
UserRates.Where(u =>
      u.ValidFrom.Date <= date
  && (u.ValidTo ?? DateTime.MaxValue).Date >= date
  && u.BillingProperty == null
  && u.JobPosition == null
).OrderByDescending(u => u.ValidFrom)
 .FirstOrDefault();
```

Which again takes around 5 seconds to execute. I should mention, that I created an unclustered index on the UserRate table

I am just not seeing where the differences lies and I am thankful for every hint or nudge in the right direction.

Comment: There's a huge difference between `ur.ValidFrom.Date <= date` and `ValidFrom <= @date`, both logically and performance-wise. (To mention only one striking difference between the LINQ and SQL statements).

Comment: Wouldn't the linq statement get translated to an sql select statement with a "where" part, containing the above filter? I don't see your point, to be honest.

Comment: Whitespace doesn't cost, you know. For better SQL performance help, please share relevant query plans via https:/brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Please also [edit] your question and add the table and index definitions. If I had to guess, `u.ValidFrom.Date <= date` and `(u.ValidTo ?? DateTime.MaxValue).Date >= date` probably isn't helping, and very likely the `FirstOrDefault` is causing `TOP 1` to be generated, which can make the compiler think it's going to get results quickly and choose a completely different plan. You also have no `ORDER BY` in the SQL, that can make a huge difference

Comment: `ur.ValidFrom.Date` truncates the time component from the date, so it changes it before it is compared. But worse, it is not *sargable*. What that is, I recently explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68353822/861716). Steve's answer also mentions this, although not using the word sargable.

Comment: Looking at the generated SQL would at least have revealed to you that it is very different from the SQL you wrote. That's always the first step to take when trying to explain performance differences.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a profiler to capture the exact SQL Statements in both cases then compare their execution plans against the server. That may shed some light into the differences.

One thing I can spot which will be a potential performance bottleneck is that you are comparing the Date values on DateTime columns. Sometimes to gain performance you have to rely on a convention in your system that values like "ValidFrom" will always be stored as a date, or simply avoiding SQL-side transformations.

For example if you want to ensure that ValidFrom falls on the date:

```
var validFrom = date.AddDays(1);

var latestUserRate = context.UserRates
    .Where(ur => ur.BillingProperty == null 
        && ur.JobPosition == null
        && ur.ValidFrom < validFrom
        && (!ur.ValidTo.HasValue || ur.ValidTo >= date))
    .OrderByDescending(ur => ur.ValidFrom)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

The main point about not doing a `.Date` comparison would be so that the server can utilize the indexes on the table effectively. The less "adjusting" you do to values from the tables, generally the better.

Differences in execution times between similar queries can boil down to things like index usage and execution plan selection. Sometimes that does require capturing the SQL in question to take a closer look then investigate recommended indexing changes and possible alternatives to eliminate poorly generated statements.

Comment: Don't forget that EF will give you the SQL, you don't have to use profiler anymore :) That would be useful advice to show OP so they can debug this in the future for themselves